# Sticky navigation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, nav

I am doing a sticky nav but when i scroll fast it doesn´t work.. only when i scroll slowly would work but not always..

Here is the CSS:

```
div.sticky {
    position: fixed;
}
```

and the Javascript:

```
     window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_lista")[0];
        if(window.scrollY > 200) {
            nav.className += " " + "sticky";
            nav.style.top = 0;
        } else if (window.scrollY < 200) {
            nav.classList.remove("sticky");
            nav.style.top = null;
        }
     });
```

Any idea where the bug can be?

Thanks!

Comment: A jsfiddle or a plunkr would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the following issues with your code:

1. You don't handle the case in which `window.scrollY` is exactly equal
   to 200.
2. You're setting `style.top` in js when you can do this all in
   the css.
3. You're using `className +=` instead of `classList.add()`.

I addressed all of the above, and it works, as shown below:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  nav.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 200);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #99FFFF;
}
nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
main {
  background-color: #FF99FF;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>This is the nav</nav>
<main>This is the content</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem...

Here's a fiddle I think represents your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/5gua3nto/2/
Same snippet down here:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
 var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
 if(window.scrollY > 500) {
  nav.className += " " + "sticky";
  nav.style.top = 0;
 } else if (window.scrollY < 500) {
  nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  nav.style.top = null;
 }
});
```

```css
    div.sticky {
    position: fixed;
}

#wrap{
  height: 8000px;
  background-color: black;
}

#menu
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

body, html
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="menu">

</div>
</div>
```

There's no bug in this one, at least not in my browser.